# Correct syntax for including external CSS and js files from a view in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, syntax, cakephp-1.3

What is the correct syntax for including an external js and external CSS file in CakePHP so that these files are included in the `<head>` from within a view?

By external I mean something like "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" but I want to place it conditionally in a single view.

Comment: Google searching always produce more tricks than answers along with conflicting info and the documentation doesn't help unless you know the exact helpers involved and since stuff has been deprectated it's even more difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer from **xiaohouzi79** is correct for Cake 1.2, but the JavaScript helper has been deprecated in Cake 1.3 ([documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1450/Javascript)).

**CSS** ([documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1437/css)):

`$html->css(array('http://example.com/type.css', 'http://example.com/color.css'), null, array('inline' => false));`

**JavaScript** ([documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1589/script)):

`$html->script(array('http://example.com/script.js'), array('inline' => false));`

Comment: Would be nice if the documentation mentioned this on the methods page also http://book.cakephp.org/view/1451/Methods. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, the documentation could definitely use some work. Glad to help.

Comment: Didn't format my question properly, I wanted these to appear in the head. For the benefit of others these two function calls need to include , false, array('inline' => false)); at the end to appear in the head.

Comment: Correct. I've updated the code to match your clarified question.

Answer (score 0):

For css use the following:

```
$html->css('http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css', false, array('inline' => false));
```

For a javascript file use the following:

```
$javascript->link('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false', false);
```

btw. don't forget to include the javascript helper in the model.

Comment: This is too painful, learning curve shouldn't be related to how easily you can memorise inconsistencies in a language/framework whatever. Every time I go back to Cake I get stung by sh.. like this.